# Customizing references in Bibtopic

Tags: bibtex, citing, multibib

I am currently having a document that uses bibtopic to manage the multiple bibliographies. I use unsrt but want to differentiate between the multiple bibliographies by putting a letter in front. Meaning, the reference for bibliography A should be cited as [A01] and for bibliography B it should be cited as [B01].

How is how the bibliography looks like:
[image]

How I want it to look like:
[image]

I know something like this is possible with \newcites in multibib, however I need to use bibtopic in this document and cannot find a corresponding feature in this package. Does anybody have an idea? I thought about making different bsts but I was unable to make it work, so hopefully somebody knows an easier solution.

Thanks!

Edit: As requested, a compilable example (pdflatex will inform you to run bibtex on some file and then rerun pdflatex again). Look below for sample bib files.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{bibtopic}

\begin{document}

    Cite some: \cite{smit54} \cite{colu92}. (All references are printed anyways due to btPrintAll.)

    \begin{btSect}{bibfile1}
        \btPrintAll
    \end{btSect}
---Just a separator for the two bibliographies.---
    \begin{btSect}{bibfile2}
        \btPrintAll
    \end{btSect}

\end{document}
```

References in the database currently look like [01] for both parts. I want the ones in the first part to show as [A01] (number increasing) and the ones in the second part as [B02] (number increasing).
Bibfile1.bib could look like this (taken from aguplus package)

```
@ARTICLE{smit54,
    AUTHOR = {J. G. Smith and H. K. Weston},
    TITLE = {Nothing Particular in this Year's History},
    YEAR = {1954},
    JOURNAL = {J. Geophys. Res.},
    VOLUME = {2},
    PAGES = {14-15}
}
```

and bibfile2.bib as thus

```
@BOOK{colu92,
    AUTHOR = {Christopher Columbus},
    TITLE = {How {I} Discovered {America}},
    YEAR = {1492},
    PUBLISHER = {Hispanic Press},
    ADDRESS = {Barcelona}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a minimal, but compilable example (MWE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this is a partial solution. Someone else can come up with something better. You can use the `bibtopicprefix` package. However, I couldn't find a way to customise the references to have the numbering you want.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[sectcntreset]{bibtopic}
\usepackage{bibtopicprefix}

\begin{document}

Cite some: \cite{smit54}, \cite{smit55}, \cite{colu92}.

    \begin{btSect}{bibfile1}
   \renewcommand{\bibprefix}{A}
        \btPrintAll
    \end{btSect}
---Just a separator for the two bibliographies.---

    \begin{btSect}{bibfile2}
        \renewcommand{\bibprefix}{B}
        \btPrintAll
    \end{btSect}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I highly suggest to use the `multibib` package which is way more flexible and easier to customise. If you read the `bibtopic` manual, you'll see that there are various problems, bugs and restriction (Sections 4 and 5). See also Section 4 of the multibib package for comments.

Comment: Thanks so much. While not precisely the answer to this question, this also does the trick for me. In the long run, I'll rather switch to biblatex than multibib.